# I need tips on saving HUGE JPEG Files

Tags: print-design, print-production

im creating canvas artwork, at 30 inches x 40 inches. The files are huge and they need to be under 20mb for me to upload. I heard .tif files could keep the image quality as well as keeping a low filesize.

Also, another option is bringing it down from 300dpi to 150 dpi. Is that going to result in loss of quality of the image?

Comment: Is changing the method of delivery an option? Like, can you use Dropbox or some other file sharing service to deliver the data? That would be preferable  to lowering the artwork's quality. Depending on whether the people you're delivering to would know what to do with it or not, I suppose you could slice up the artwork, or even split the files at the bit level for later concatenation - however I seriously doubt those on the receiving end would know what to do with, or be willing to piece back together such data. Of course downscaling the DPI will result in quality loss, but what is acceptable?

Comment: What you heard about TIFF (LZW) compression is incorrect. It is lossless, but that comes at the price of a significantly larger file than a JPG of the same resolution.

Answer (score 2):

If the jpegs are too big already, then there is absolutely zero chance that a TIFF will be smaller.

150dpi is perfectly adequate for a large format print, even 120dpi would do especially if it is being printed on a textured canvas. 300 dpi is fine as well, but a bit excessive unless you think viewers will be examining the print with a magnifying glass.

30" x 40" at 150dpi is 4500px x 6000px